# Swift login to json API

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

my API accepts the following JSON to login:

```
{ "operation" : "login", "user": { "name": "username", "password": "password" } }
```

In Xcode I already tried:

```
let username : String = textFieldUserName.text!
let password : String = textFieldPassword.text!

let param = "{ \"operation\" : \"login\", \"user\": { \"username\": \"" + username + "\", \"password\": \"" + password + "\" } }"
let dict = convertToDictionary(text: param)

//making a post request
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: dict).responseJSON{
    response in
    //printing response
    print(response)
    print (param)
    //other handling removed
}
```

Function to convert to dictionary:

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The Postman request is: POST to http://myserver/api/v1/logmein/login.php
The request body is set to raw and contains: `{ "operation" : "login", "user": { "name": "username", "password": "password" } }`

But the response from my API is always the error message for wrong parameters... If I paste the param from the console to Postman and fire a request, everything works fine.

Maybe someone could help me out?

Comment: Try without serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not generate a JSON object manually from a `String`. `Alamofire` accepts a `Dictionary` as the request body, so use a `Dictionary` and to not generate a `String`, convert that to `Data`, then try to decode it as if it was a `JSON` encoded data, since it never was proper `JSON` data.

```
let requestParameters = ["operation":"login","user":["name":"username","password":"password"]]
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: requestParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{...
```

Comment: I have copied your snippet but it still doesn't work... API responds with an error...

Comment: My API responds with "wrong parameters" (this can be either wrong username or password or wrong request)

Comment: Does the same request with the same parameters work from another source, say, Postman?

Comment: If I print the requestParameters to the console I got: "["user": ["school_id": "12344-s", "password": "tom"], "operation": "login"]" which can't work because it doesn't match the required format (see in question)

Comment: Other than the fact that you changed name to school_id, the format is exactly the same as the on in your question.

Comment: That was a try with another API but both won't accept the request... How can we get curly brackets to the request?

Comment: The curly brackets are just formatting for printing, you shouldn't care about those, that is not the issue.

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything. Please include your Postman request in your question and I will check if everything matches.

Comment: Question edited... API doesn't accept the request with square brackets...

Comment: From Postman of course that doesn't work. In the JSON format, square brackets represent arrays while curly brackets represent dictionaries. However, in Swift source code, dictionaries are represented as `[key:value,key:value...]` and arrays as `[value,value...]`, so this doesn't make a difference. I will check your update in a moment

Comment: I just realised that you haven't added the `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` part to your Alamofire request, check out now.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it a simpler way by Dictionary only

```
var dic: [String: Any] = [:]
dic["operation"] = "login"
let user: [String: Any] = ["name": "username", "password": "password"]
dic["user"] = user

Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: dic, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { ... }
```

seems like you miss the encoding?

Comment: I'm sorry but this code doesn't work :( API still responds with error.